# Getting gradle errors in a Flutter application after importing packages

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm building a Flutter app, and just added the mime and http_parser packages.  After that I got the following error when building:

```
<appname>\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:35: AAPT: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka com.att.fluttercount:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
```

Up until now, the app had built just fine.  I backed out my changes, including removing the packages from pubspec.yaml, but the error won't go away.

Here's the relevant part of my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_map: ^0.5.0+1
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+9
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.6
  sqflite: ^1.1.5
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  #mime: ^0.9.6+2
  #http_parser: ^3.1.3

  # Must use 'any' as the version of path_provider, because other packages depend on
  # earlier versions of path_provider.
  path_provider: any

  # Note: Must use 'any' as the version of uuid, because some dependencies of flutter_map
  # depend on earlier versions of uuid.
  uuid: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this errror?

Comment: It looks like the `google play services` library is missing from your gradle file. Have you tried to add its configuration ?

Comment: @Moujabr - No, I have not tried to add google play services, but I'm wondering why I am getting this error when I did not get it before, and am still getting it, even after removing the newly-added dependencies on mime and http_parser.

Answer (score 0):

I had neglected to mention that I had also *removed* a dependency on google_maps_flutter, which I was no longer using.  I added this dependency back in, and the error went away.